Приложение winforms c# 4.8, подключенное к Firebird 2.5 зависает, а сервер передает ошибку 10054
Недавно мы обновили версию приложения с Net 4.0 => 4.8, провайдер Firebird 2.1.0.0 => 2.7.0.0, заменили передачу типа транзакции FbTransactionOptions.ReadCommitted => System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommited, а также вынесли выполнение крупных и продолжительных(5+ сек) select запросов в фоновые задачи. Теперь у некоторых пользователей стало навечно зависать приложение, оно поедает ресурсы и нет свойственного эффекта от зависания (Не отвечает), как будто происходит взаимоблокировка потоков, о чем также свидетельствуют дампы памяти зависших приложений. Причем зависание происходит не в момент непосредственной работы с приложением, а после непродолжительного простоя(от пары минут и более), когда им даже не пользовались. У кого-то при выходе из спящего режима, а у кото-то и без него, но уже после того, как все фоновые загрузки завершились. Таймеров и прочего, что могло запуститься в работу спустя время на формах нет. Сервер в логах в момент зависания регистрирует ошибку 10054, хотя он и до обновления регистрировал эти ошибки(неполадок ранее это не вызывало). Ошибка скорее всего связана с нестабильным сетевым подключением по неким ИЗВЕСТНЫМ причинам, но данная ошибка вызывает зависание лишь у некоторых пользователей(причем у них зависание происходит каждый раз при возникновении этой ошибки(на Windows 10, 11 и по-моему 7)).
Основное подключение к базе идет со включенным пулом потоков, оно открывается с момента запуска приложения и закрывается при выходе. Фоновые подключения идут с выключенным пулом потоков.
Вот пример фоновых загрузок:
CancellationTokenSource token = null;
public bool IsBusy => token != null;

private void SomeFunc()
{
    if (IsBusy)
        return;
    token = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        FbConnection con = null;

        try
        {
            Action action = () =>
            {
                // Обязательные действия до выполнения полезной нагрузки
            };
            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(action);
            else
                action();

            con = GetTempCon(); // Тут просто копируется текст подключения основного подключения, добавляется приставка Pooling=false и открывается соединение

            // Полезная нагрузка

            token.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (this.IsHandleCreated)
            {
                action = () =>
                {
                    // Действия при успешном выполнении полезной нагрузки
                };
                if (InvokeRequired)
                    Invoke(action);
                else
                    action();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Если операция отменена
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            // Обработка ошибок
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                con = null;
            }
            if (token != null)
            {
                token.Dispose();
                token = null;
            }
            if (this.IsHandleCreated)
            {
                Action action = () =>
                {
                    // Обязательные действия после выполнения полезной нагрузки
                };
                if (InvokeRequired)
                    Invoke(action);
                else
                    action();
            }
        }
    });
}

Мы пробовали откатить версию провайдера, тип транзакции и Net с заменой вызовов Task.Run на Task.Factory.StartNew, но ничего не помогло. В будущем мы планируем переход на новую версию Firebird, но решение нужно сейчас.

Несколько странный код. Если вы затачиваетесь на многопоточность, то почему проверка повторного входа и выставление флага идут не под блокировкой? Что будет, если эксепшен выпадет в блоке finally, где у вас какая-то бизнес-логика есть? Куда этот эксепшен упадёт, учитывая, что вы не ожидаете завершения запускаемой через Task.Run задачи, да и метод, который запускает задачу, у вас имеет тип void? Я не могу точно сказать, в этом ли засада, но код явно нуждается в улучшении, сейчас он не выглядит безопасным.

Блоки action выполняют небольшой список действий, связанный с элементами GUI, в их содержимом я не сомневаюсь. В finally меня интересует только con.State. Может ли он иметь какие-либо статусы, кроме Closed, которые при попытке закрытия вызовут исключение? Если обернуть подключение в using(), то как он очищает ресурсы при выходе из него? Нужно ли закрывать подключение или при выходе он сам безопасно закроет его?

Кстати, да, явный вызов Dispose - это тоже какой-то антипаттерн, IDisposable должны использоваться через using, тогда они сами автоматом диспозятся при выходе из текущего блока кода. А что касается GUI, то если изначально вызов этого метода идёт из GUI, то лучше перепишите всё на нормальную асинхронность и не нужно будет никаких Invoke, если всё правильно написать, всё будет в потоке GUI спокойно выполняться асинхронно. А что выполняется долго, то отдельным таском можете запустить.

Налицо плавающий дедлок, но глядя на обрезанный код без даже кода вызывающего метода, здесь мало что можно сказать. Для нормального анализа нужно всё: код вызова начиная с обработчика события или команды, заканчивая всеми дочерними функциями. В противном случае это угадайка.
Одно могу сказать, этот код можно без единого инвока написать, полностью асинхронно, отвязав от интерфейса совсем, что даже вероятные дедлоки не будут вешать гуй, но начну с простого - избавлюсь от инвоков.
private CancellationTokenSource cts = null;
public bool IsBusy => cts != null;

private async Task SomeFuncAsync()
{
    using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        // Обязательные действия с UI до выполнения полезной нагрузки
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (FbConnection con = GetTempCon())
                {
                    // Полезная нагрузка
                    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    // Ещё полезная нагрузка
                }

                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            });

            // Действия с UI при успешном выполнении полезной нагрузки
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            // Обработка ошибок
        }
        // Обязательные действия с UI после выполнения полезной нагрузки
    }
    cts = null;
}

Вообще без инвоков.
Вызывающий код, позволяющий организовать асинхронный вызов, будет выглядеть так:
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsBusy)
        return;
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.Enabled = false;
    await SomeFuncAsync();
    btn.Enabled = true;
}

Такое исполнение обработчика события допустимо только если есть гарантия, что SomeFuncAsync не выбросит исключение ни при каких обстоятельствах. В противном случае, его требуется обернуть в try-catch с перехватом Exception.
Обратите внимание, что метод SomeFuncAsync предназначен только для вызова в контексте UI потока, то есть вот так await Task.Run(SomeFuncAsync) делать нельзя.

Переписал код под вашу версию, зависания остаются такие же как и ранее.

@Fame0wner значит где-то ошиблись или где-то опять инвоки. Если за пределами Task.Run никакого долгоиграющего кода нет, то и подвисаний быть не должно. К сожалению только по фразе "у меня не работает" я не могу найти источник проблемы.

@Fame0wner удалось разобраться?

вроде бы да, пошаманили еще с настройками и по видимому старая версия провайдера тоже влияла на зависания. Провайдер 2.7 и фоновые загрузки в вашем исполнении пока работают без зависаний. Благодарю за помощь!
